# SWIFT 5: Increment Value Async of Determinate Circular Progress Indicator

Tags: swift

I searched a lot but I can't find a good explanation of using a determinate circular progress indicator.

I have a Helper-Class that converts a PDF to an image. I have more than 400 pages so I decided to make these things asynchron with the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: pdfDocument.numberOfPages) { i in
    … do the work …
    view.incrementProgressIndicator()
}
```

Insight the view, where the ProgressIndicator lives, the called function looks the following:

```
func incrementProgressIndicator() {
    self.progressIndicator.increment(by: 1)
}
```

For sure, Swift says: "UI API called on a background thread".

I tried to surround the code of incrementing with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.progressIndicator.increment(by: 1)
}
```

But now, all the work of indicating is done **after** the conversion of PDF is completed.

Can someone tell my how this can be done? I can't find a working tutorial for my issue.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my issue. I replace the

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: pdfDocument.numberOfPages) { i in
    … do the work …
    view.incrementProgressIndicator()
}
```

with the following code:

```
for i in 0..<pdfDocument.numberOfPages {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let pdfPage = pdfDocument.page(at: i + 1)!
                if let result = self.convertPageToImage(withPdfPage: pdfPage, sourceURL: sourceURL, destUrl: destinationURL, index: i) {
                    urls[i] = result
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let delegate = self.delegate {
                        print("Ask for Increment")
                        delegate.incrementProgressIndicator()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```